# "More hot questions" doesn't work when you are not logged in

Tags: bug, hot-questions

Sometimes I feel like wandering aimlessly through all the hot questions, but sometimes I land in a place I have no account. When I finish my reading and try to find something else interesting, I go to the hot list questions and press "More hot questions" link which ends only adding a # in the url.

How to reproduce:

1. Go to a question in a site you are not logged in
2. Click "More hot questions"

Comment: No repro for me. What site exactly? What browser? Any JS errors in the console?

Comment: @ShadowWizard any, iceweasel (firefox), no

Comment: I think iceweasel isn't supported. See [this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193016/expanding-comment-list-does-not-work), maybe you also allow only partial JS hence it's causing you such problems. Try with real Firefox browser and see.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Iceweasel is just Firefox rebranded...](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44216/41104) they change nothing on the backend...

Comment: I don't really agree. It's still a different code, fat finger might cause a bug that does not exist in the real Firefox. If something works in FF and doesn't work in IW it kind of proves this point.

Comment: @ShadowWizard well, they say that only the branding change, and it's supported by SE (since most debian systems use a version of IceWeasel) so it's a bug.

Comment: Norepro on Firefox 27 / Windows 7. Can you test in [safe mode](http://playingwithsid.blogspot.fi/2007/11/firefoxiceweasel-tip-use-safe-mode-to.html) and see if the problem persists? If not, it's probably an extension issue.

Comment: This will just be closed as no-repro since you can't expect the devs to test with every fork that ever existed of every browser and it works in all real browsers.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I used Private Mode (which disables the extensions up to what I have understood) but still persist.

Comment: No, Private Browsing mode in Firefox / Iceweasel [does not disable extensions](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/926986). You need Safe Mode (= "Restart with Add-ons Disabled...") for that.

Comment: If Private Browsing disabled extensions I'd be one annoyed incognito user.